# CMSMS FormBuilder's form simply reload without error when file too large

Tags: formbuilder, cmsmadesimple

Using CMSMS 1.6.6 with FormBuilder plugin 0.6.1

I've got a file upload field with a size limitation of 5000KB and some extensions: JPG, GIF, PNG.

**BUG:** When I try to send a completed form with a large file (like a 10MB FLV) as attachment, I got absolutely no error message and the form simply reloads (not the .thank you" template).

But if I try to upload a wrong file extension, but within the size limitatons (like a FLV 2MB) then I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an ancient version of both CMS Made Simple (1.6.6. is from 2009) and the same goes for the Formbuilder version.

I strongly recommend you make a backup of your current install and then upgrade to the the latest version of CMS Made Simple, which is currently 1.11.6. Please note it requires PHP 5.3 and GCB names have gotten restrictions. Please read the release notes.

If your issue persists after upgrade, you can file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the bug wasn't even CMSMS nor FormBuilder -- it was a MaxUpload issue.

I solved it by putting a php.ini file (hosting allowed it) within the CMS folder, with those lines:

upload_max_filesize = "250M"
post_max_size = "250M"